what is the way to change the thread paramters like pitch using the API script?
I think i wasnt very clear in my question, sorry for that. I want to automate the bolt generation process (generating 100 bolts each time the script is run) wherein the paramters of the bolt are varied like all the default paramters like diameter, length etc and also wanted to vary the thread feature of each bolt like pitch and thread type as well.I am looking for a way to access the XML files through script but instead of indirectly accessing through the recommended function part, access it directly, is this somehow possible?   I need to perform these tasks in order to generate a datasetof 1000 different bolts in stl format to run an ML model for CAD file classification based on the parameters. I am kind off facing issues in the script part where i want to query threads with different pitch each time it is generated.
sideFace = bodyExt.sideFaces[0]
threads = newComp.features.threadFeatures
threadDataQuery = threads.threadDataQuery
defaultThreadType = threadDataQuery.defaultMetricThreadType
recommendData = threadDataQuery.recommendThreadData(self.bodyDiameter, False, defaultThreadType)
if recommendData[0] : threadInfo = threads.createThreadInfo(False, defaultThreadType, recommendData[1], recommendData[2]) faces = adsk.core.ObjectCollection.create() faces.add(sideFace) threadInput = threads.createInput(faces, threadInfo) threads.add(threadInput) except: if ui: ui.messageBox('Failed to compute the bolt. This is most likely because the input values define an invalid bolt.')
I suppose I would have to make changes in this part of the sample script which i have taken from the product documentation page pf fusion 360 but on changing the recommendData[0] , recommendData[1], recommendData[2] to any other values like recommendData[3] or recommendData[4], fusion throws an error saying invalid params and genarates a plain bolt without any threads.I am aware of the fact that the all thread definitions are stored in XML files, where in the ThreadDataQuery object in API allows one to query these XML files.How to query the XML files in order to vary the pitch of the bolt generated?
I am attaching below the metricTappingThreadsForPlastics.xml and the script that I am facing issue with in the form of 2 code blocks. can you please help me with the script part, suggesting changes on how to be able to vary the pitch of the thread in bolt gneration using the script please ?
the threads for plstics xml looks something like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ThreadType>
  <Name>Metric Tapping Threads for Plastics</Name>
  <CustomName>Metric Tapping Threads for Plastics</CustomName>
  <Unit>mm</Unit>
  <Angle>30</Angle>
  <SortOrder>26</SortOrder>
  <ExternalOnly>yes</ExternalOnly>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>1.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1x0.44</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1x0.44</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.44</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>0.82</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.64</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>1.2</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.2x0.51</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.2x0.51</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.51</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.2</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>0.99</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.78</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.2x0.53</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.2x0.53</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.53</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.2</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>0.97</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.74</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>1.4</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.4x0.57</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.4x0.57</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.57</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.4</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.165</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.93</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.4x0.62</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.4x0.62</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.62</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.4</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.12</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.84</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>1.5</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.5x0.67</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.5x0.67</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.67</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.5</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.195</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.89</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>1.6</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.6x0.64</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.6x0.64</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.64</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.6</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.335</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.07</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.6x0.67</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.6x0.67</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.67</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.6</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.26</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>0.92</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>1.8</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.8x0.71</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.8x0.71</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.71</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.8</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.51</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.22</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>1.8x0.8</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>1.8x0.8</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.8</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>1.8</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.42</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.04</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>2.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>2x0.78</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>2x0.78</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.78</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>2.00</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.68</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.36</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>2x0.89</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>2x0.89</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.89</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>2.00</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.575</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.15</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>2.2</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>2.2x0.85</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>2.2x0.85</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.85</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>2.20</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.855</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.51</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>2.2x0.98</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>2.2x0.98</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.98</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>2.20</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.775</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.25</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>2.5</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>2.5x0.95</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>2.5x0.95</CTD>
      <Pitch>0.95</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>2.50</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.76</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.72</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>2.5x1.12</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>2.5x1.12</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.12</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>2.50</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>1.95</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.40</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>3.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>3x1.12</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>3x1.12</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.12</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>3.00</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>2.545</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>2.09</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>3x1.34</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>3x1.34</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.34</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>3.00</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>2.73</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.66</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>3.5</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>3.5x1.29</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>3.5x1.29</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.29</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>3.5</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>2.975</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>2.45</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>3.5x1.57</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>3.5x1.57</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.57</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>3.5</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>2.58</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>1.66</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>4.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>4x1.46</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>4x1.46</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.46</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>4.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>3.405</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>2.81</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>4x1.79</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>4x1.79</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.79</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>4.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>3.34</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>2.17</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>4.5</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>4.5x1.63</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>4.5x1.63</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.63</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>4.5</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>3.835</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>3.17</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>5.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>5x1.8</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>5x1.8</CTD>
      <Pitch>1.8</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>5.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>4.765</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>3.53</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>5x2.24</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>5x2.24</CTD>
      <Pitch>2.24</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>5.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>3.84</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>2.68</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>6.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>6x2.14</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>6x2.14</CTD>
      <Pitch>2.14</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>6.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>5.63</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>4.26</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>6x2.69</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>6x2.69</CTD>
      <Pitch>2.69</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>6.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>4.595</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>3.19</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>
  <ThreadSize>
    <Size>7.0</Size>
    <Designation>
      <ThreadDesignation>7x2.48</ThreadDesignation>
      <CTD>7x2.48</CTD>
      <Pitch>2.48</Pitch>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>external</Gender>
        <Class>h14</Class>
        <MajorDia>7.0</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>5.99</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>4.98</MinorDia>
      </Thread>
    

Current script which is failing to generate any bolt with threads
import adsk.core, adsk.fusion, traceback
import math
import random
import time
import os
import json

defaultBoltName = 'Bolt'
defaultHeadDiameter = 0.75
defaultBodyDiameter = 0.5
defaultHeadHeight = 0.3125
defaultBodyLength = 1.0
defaultCutAngle = 30.0 * (math.pi / 180)
defaultChamferDistance = 0.03845
defaultFilletRadius = 0.02994

handlers = []
app = adsk.core.Application.get()
if app:
    ui = app.userInterface

class ThreadData:
    def __init__(self, threadFeatures):
        self.threadDataQuery = threadFeatures.threadDataQuery
        self.threadTypes = self.threadDataQuery.allThreadTypes
        self.threadData = []
        
        # Collect all available thread data
        for threadType in self.threadTypes:
            sizes = self.threadDataQuery.allSizes(threadType)
            for size in sizes:
                designations = self.threadDataQuery.allDesignations(threadType, size)
                for designation in designations:
                    classes = self.threadDataQuery.allClasses(False, threadType, designation)
                    for threadClass in classes:
                        self.threadData.append({
                            'type': threadType,
                            'size': size,
                            'designation': designation,
                            'class': threadClass
                        })
    
    def getRandomThreadInfo(self, threadFeatures, minDiameter, maxDiameter):
        valid_threads = []
        
        for thread in self.threadData:
            # Get the nominal diameter for this thread
            threadInfo = threadFeatures.createThreadInfo(
                False, 
                thread['type'],
                thread['designation'],
                thread['class']
            )
            diameter = threadInfo.nominalDiameter
            
            # Check if diameter is within our range
            if minDiameter <= diameter <= maxDiameter:
                valid_threads.append(thread)
        
        if not valid_threads:
            return None
            
        # Select a random thread from valid options
        selected = random.choice(valid_threads)
        return threadFeatures.createThreadInfo(
            False,
            selected['type'],
            selected['designation'],
            selected['class']
        )

class Bolt:
    def __init__(self):
        self._boltName = defaultBoltName
        self._headDiameter = defaultHeadDiameter
        self._bodyDiameter = defaultBodyDiameter
        self._headHeight = defaultHeadHeight
        self._bodyLength = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(defaultBodyLength)
        self._cutAngle = defaultCutAngle
        self._chamferDistance = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(defaultChamferDistance)
        self._filletRadius = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(defaultFilletRadius)
        
    # Property getters and setters remain the same as in your original code
    @property
    def boltName(self):
        return self._boltName
    @boltName.setter
    def boltName(self, value):
        self._boltName = value

    @property
    def headDiameter(self):
        return self._headDiameter
    @headDiameter.setter
    def headDiameter(self, value):
        self._headDiameter = value

    @property
    def bodyDiameter(self):
        return self._bodyDiameter
    @bodyDiameter.setter
    def bodyDiameter(self, value):
        self._bodyDiameter = value

    @property
    def headHeight(self):
        return self._headHeight
    @headHeight.setter
    def headHeight(self, value):
        self._headHeight = value

    @property
    def bodyLength(self):
        return self._bodyLength
    @bodyLength.setter
    def bodyLength(self, value):
        self._bodyLength = value

    @property
    def cutAngle(self):
        return self._cutAngle
    @cutAngle.setter
    def cutAngle(self, value):
        self._cutAngle = value

    @property
    def chamferDistance(self):
        return self._chamferDistance
    @chamferDistance.setter
    def chamferDistance(self, value):
        self._chamferDistance = value

    @property
    def filletRadius(self):
        return self._filletRadius
    @filletRadius.setter
    def filletRadius(self, value):
        self._filletRadius = value

    def buildBolt(self, component, threadData):
        try:
            newComp = component 
            # Create hexagonal head and body (same as original code)
            sketches = newComp.sketches
            xyPlane = newComp.xYConstructionPlane
            xzPlane = newComp.xZConstructionPlane
            sketch = sketches.add(xyPlane)
            center = adsk.core.Point3D.create(0, 0, 0)  
            # Create hexagonal head
            vertices = []
            for i in range(6):
                vertex = adsk.core.Point3D.create(
                    center.x + (self.headDiameter/2) * math.cos(math.pi * i / 3),
                    center.y + (self.headDiameter/2) * math.sin(math.pi * i / 3),
                    0
                )
                vertices.append(vertex)
            for i in range(6):
     sketch.sketchCurves.sketchLines.addByTwoPoints(vertices[(i+1) % 6], vertices[i])
            # Extrude head
            extrudes = newComp.features.extrudeFeatures
            prof = sketch.profiles[0]
            extInput = extrudes.createInput(prof, adsk.fusion.FeatureOperations.NewBodyFeatureOperation)
            distance = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(self.headHeight)
            extInput.setDistanceExtent(False, distance)
            headExt = extrudes.add(extInput)
            # Name the body
            fc = headExt.faces[0]
            bd = fc.body
            bd.name = self.boltName
            # Create the body
            bodySketch = sketches.add(xyPlane)
   bodySketch.sketchCurves.sketchCircles.addByCenterRadius(center, self.bodyDiameter/2)

            bodyProf = bodySketch.profiles[0]
            bodyExtInput = extrudes.createInput(bodyProf, adsk.fusion.FeatureOperations.JoinFeatureOperation)
            bodyExtInput.setAllExtent(adsk.fusion.ExtentDirections.NegativeExtentDirection)
            bodyExtInput.setDistanceExtent(False, self.bodyLength)
            bodyExt = extrudes.add(bodyExtInput)

            # Create chamfer and fillet (same as original code)
            edgeCol = adsk.core.ObjectCollection.create()
            edges = bodyExt.endFaces[0].edges
            for edgeI in edges:
                edgeCol.add(edgeI)

            chamferFeats = newComp.features.chamferFeatures
            chamferInput = chamferFeats.createInput(edgeCol, True)
            chamferInput.setToEqualDistance(self.chamferDistance)
            chamferFeats.add(chamferInput)

            # Create fillet
            edgeCol.clear()
            loops = headExt.endFaces[0].loops
            for edgeLoop in loops:
                if len(edgeLoop.edges) == 1:
                    edgeCol.add(edgeLoop.edges[0])
                    break

            filletFeats = newComp.features.filletFeatures
            filletInput = filletFeats.createInput()
            filletInput.addConstantRadiusEdgeSet(edgeCol, self.filletRadius, True)
            filletFeats.add(filletInput)

            # Create revolve features for bolt head
            self.createRevolveFeature(newComp, xzPlane, center, self.headDiameter/2, self.headHeight, self.cutAngle)

            # Create thread feature using ThreadData
            sideFace = bodyExt.sideFaces[0]
            threads = newComp.features.threadFeatures
            
            # Get appropriate thread info for the bolt diameter
            threadInfo = threadData.getRandomThreadInfo(
                threads,
                self.bodyDiameter * 0.9,  # Allow some tolerance
                self.bodyDiameter * 1.1
            )
            
            if threadInfo:
                faces = adsk.core.ObjectCollection.create()
                faces.add(sideFace)
                threadInput = threads.createInput(faces, threadInfo)
                threadInput.isModeled = True
                threadInput.threadLength = self.bodyLength
                threads.add(threadInput)

            return True
        except:
            if ui:
                ui.messageBox(f'Failed to compute the bolt {self.boltName}. This is most likely because the input values define an invalid bolt.')
            return False

    def createRevolveFeature(self, component, plane, center, radius, height, angle):
        sketches = component.sketches
        revolveSketch = sketches.add(plane)
        
        point1 = revolveSketch.modelToSketchSpace(adsk.core.Point3D.create(center.x + radius*math.cos(math.pi/6), 0, center.y))
        point2 = revolveSketch.modelToSketchSpace(adsk.core.Point3D.create(center.x + radius, 0, center.y))
        point3 = revolveSketch.modelToSketchSpace(adsk.core.Point3D.create(point2.x, 0, (point2.x - point1.x) * math.tan(angle)))
        
        revolveSketch.sketchCurves.sketchLines.addByTwoPoints(point1, point2)
        revolveSketch.sketchCurves.sketchLines.addByTwoPoints(point2, point3)
        revolveSketch.sketchCurves.sketchLines.addByTwoPoints(point3, point1)

        zAxis = component.zConstructionAxis
        revolves = component.features.revolveFeatures
        revProf = revolveSketch.profiles[0]
        revInput = revolves.createInput(revProf, zAxis, adsk.fusion.FeatureOperations.CutFeatureOperation)
        revAngle = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(math.pi*2)
        revInput.setAngleExtent(False, revAngle)
        revolves.add(revInput)

def run(context):
    ui = None
    try:
        app = adsk.core.Application.get()
        ui = app.userInterface
        product = app.activeProduct
        design = adsk.fusion.Design.cast(product)

        if not design:
            ui.messageBox('It is not supported in current workspace, please change to MODEL workspace and try again.')
            return

        root = design.rootComponent
        threadData = ThreadData(root.features.threadFeatures)

        # File to store the current bolt count and random seed
        config_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'bolt_config.json')

        # Load or initialize configuration
        if os.path.exists(config_file):
            with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
                config = json.load(f)
            current_bolt_count = config['bolt_count']
            random_seed = config['random_seed']
        else:
            current_bolt_count = 0
            random_seed = int(time.time())

        # Set the random seed
        random.seed(random_seed)

        def create_bolt(params, x, y, z):
            try:
                bolt = Bolt()
                bolt.boltName = params['name']
                bolt.headDiameter = params['headDiameter']
                bolt.bodyDiameter = params['bodyDiameter']
                bolt.headHeight = params['headHeight']
                bolt.bodyLength = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(params['bodyLength'])
                bolt.cutAngle = params['cutAngle']
                bolt.chamferDistance = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(params['chamferDistance'])
                bolt.filletRadius = adsk.core.ValueInput.createByReal(params['filletRadius'])

                transform = adsk.core.Matrix3D.create()
                transform.translation = adsk.core.Vector3D.create(x, y, z)
                boltOcc = root.occurrences.addNewComponent(transform)
                success = bolt.buildBolt(boltOcc.component, threadData)
                
                if success:
                    export_as_stl(boltOcc.component, params['name'])
                else:
                    if boltOcc:
                        boltOcc.deleteMe()
                
                return success
            except:
                print(f"Failed to create bolt: {params['name']}")
                if 'boltOcc' in locals() and boltOcc:
                    boltOcc.deleteMe()
                return False

        def generate_valid_bolt_params(index):
            # Start with the body diameter as our base parameter
            body_diameter = 0.5  # Fixed body diameter
            
            # Fixed relationships that are known to work
            head_diameter = 0.75  # 1.5 times body diameter
            head_height = 0.3125  # Standard proportion
            body_length = 1.0  # 2 times body diameter
            
            # Small variations in chamfer and fillet
            chamfer_distance = 0.03845
            fillet_radius = 0.02994
            
            # Add very small random variations to prevent exact duplicates
            variation = 0.001  # 0.1% variation
            
            return {
                'name': f'Bolt{index}',
                'headDiameter': head_diameter * (1 + random.uniform(-variation, variation)),
                'bodyDiameter': body_diameter * (1 + random.uniform(-variation, variation)),
                'headHeight': head_height * (1 + random.uniform(-variation, variation)),
                'bodyLength': body_length * (1 + random.uniform(-variation, variation)),
                'cutAngle': 30.0 * (math.pi / 180),
                'chamferDistance': chamfer_distance * (1 + random.uniform(-variation, variation)),
                'filletRadius': fillet_radius * (1 + random.uniform(-variation, variation))
            }

        def export_as_stl(component, name):
            try:
                exportMgr = adsk.fusion.ExportManager.cast(design.exportManager)
                stlOptions = exportMgr.createSTLExportOptions(component)
                
                desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
                stl_folder = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'stl_files')
                
                if not os.path.exists(stl_folder):
                    os.makedirs(stl_folder)
                
                filename = os.path.join(stl_folder, f'{name}.stl')
                stlOptions.filename = filename

                exportMgr.execute(stlOptions)
                print(f"Successfully exported {name}.stl to {stl_folder}")
            except:
                print(f"Failed to export {name}.stl")

        # Generate bolts with new parameter generation
        num_bolts = 100
        grid_size = int(num_bolts ** 0.5) + 1
        spacing = 2.0  # Increased spacing to prevent overlap

        successful_bolts = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        
        for i in range(num_bolts):
            params = generate_valid_bolt_params(current_bolt_count + i + 1)
            row = i // grid_size
            col = i % grid_size
            x = col * spacing
            y = row * spacing
            z = 0
            if create_bolt(params, x, y, z):
                successful_bolts += 1
                print(f"Successfully created bolt {params['name']}")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to create bolt {params['name']}")
            if (i + 1) % (num_bolts // 10) == 0:
                progress = (i + 1) / num_bolts * 100
                elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                estimated_total_time = elapsed_time / (progress / 100)
                remaining_time = estimated_total_time - elapsed_time
                print(f"Progress: {progress:.1f}% - Estimated time remaining: {remaining_time:.1f} seconds")      
            adsk.doEvents()
        total_time = time.time() - start_time
        # Update and save configuration
        current_bolt_count += successful_bolts
        random_seed = random.randint(0, 1000000)  # Generate new seed for next run
        config = {'bolt_count': current_bolt_count, 'random_seed': random_seed}
        with open(config_file, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(config, f)
        ui.messageBox(f'Created and exported {successful_bolts} bolts successfully.\n'
                     f'Total bolts created so far: {current_bolt_count}\n'
                     f'Total time taken: {total_time:.1f} seconds\n'
                     f'STL files are saved in the "stl_files" folder on your desktop.')
    except:
        if ui:
       ui.messageBox('Failed:\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
